# OpenGL Display Lists

Tags: list, opengl, matrix

Can someone please explain to me how to modify a display list in OpenGL once its compiled? How can I enforce, for example a matrix transformation on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a vertex buffer object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Display lists are immutable; you cannot alter them once created. That's pretty much the point of them.

If you want to have geometry built into a display list that can be rendered at a place defined by a matrix, you simply don't put matrix commands in the display list. Just put the drawing stuff in a display list. When you want to render that geometry, do the setup work (including matrix stuff) and then execute the display list.

Your current code looks something like this:

```
//Every frame
glRotatef(...);
glTranslatef(...);

///More setup work.

glBegin(...);
glVertex/TexCoord/Color/etc(...);
...
glEnd();
```

Your display list-based code should look like this:

```
//Initialization. Done once.
glBeginList(...);
glBegin(...);
glVertex/TexCoord/Color/etc(...);
...
glEnd();
glEndList();

//Every frame
glRotatef(...);
glTranslatef(...);
...

glCallList(...);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand! How do you do the "setup work"? what exactly do you mean by that? Can you expand? (specifically I don't get to what do you apply the matrix and how to do it)

Comment: @user10607: Can you render stuff without display lists? If so, then do that. Then put all of the `glBegin/End` stuff in a display list, and call that list in the place you would have used `glBegin/End`. If you don't know how to render stuff without a display list, then you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: No I get to this part alright. But this is like rendering the scene, what if I have to move a huge mesh around all the time? Tons of faces and vertices, I heard it was possible to load it all into a Display List, so then you just move the list coordinates (somehow!) which is much fast. Much faster than supplying the vertices coordinates to OpenGL every frame.

Comment: You do it like that: `glTransform(..)/glRotate(..); glCallList(..);` This way your list will be rendered with specified transform/rotate.

Comment: Ok, so I supply a command to Rotate for example, but then I have to cancel it after I rotated a specific object. And how can one do that? And Krom, is it glTransform? My code raises an error when I try glTransfrorm(whatever!).

Comment: You can revert the rotate/transform surrounding it with glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix pair. Please mark the answer "accepted" if it helped :)